# Access to intent slots from lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, amazon-lex

I created a simple bot with a simple lex intent. This lex intent has one single slot `slotTwo`.

Then I linked it with a python lambda function. I want to access to the value of that slot from inside the lambda function.

python lambda function receives the parameters `context` and `event`. The link below shows the structure for the parameter `event`. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html

```
I copy it here too:


{
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "intent-name",
    "slots": {
      "slot name": "value",
      "slot name": "value"
    },
    "slotDetails": {
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      },
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      }
    },
    "confirmationStatus": "None, Confirmed, or Denied (intent confirmation, if configured)"
  },
  "bot": {
    "name": "bot name",
    "alias": "bot alias",
    "version": "bot version"
  },
  "userId": "User ID specified in the POST request to Amazon Lex.",
  "inputTranscript": "Text used to process the request",
  "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook or DialogCodeHook",
  "outputDialogMode": "Text or Voice, based on ContentType request header in runtime API request",
  "messageVersion": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": { 
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
  },
  "requestAttributes": { 
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
  }
}
```

However, when I print out the content of this parameter I see only the slot and I can access to its value directly, first level.

```
START RequestId: 60a541d8-b3c8-48b0-a7a3-6b3f65d96482 Version: $LATEST
{
"slotTwo": "some text here"
}
```

The test from the lambda console works fine. It is able to retrieve the value and continue the logic.
However when I test the bot from Lex it does not work.
Any idea why? 
Thanks so much
Ester

Comment: How are you attempting to get the slot value? Did you try: `event.currentIntent.slots.slotOne` If that's not the simple answer, then we will need to see at least some of your Lambda code to help.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.
I missed that the values indicated in the lamdda test must correspond to the whole JSON structure. So now I added this as event test:

```
{
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "intent-name",
    "slots": {
      "slotTwo": "Hi from the sendmessagetest"
    }
  }
}
```

and I access the slot within the lambda this way:

```
 messagetext = event['currentIntent'] ['slots'] ['slotTwo']
```

Feel free to delete my post if you find it confusing.
Thanks everyone